# Join date and time to datetime in model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails 5 app has a model with a column scheduled_at (`datetime`). In my form I have to fields schedule_date and schedule_time using `attr_accessor`:

```
attr_accessor :schedule_date, :schedule_time
```

Now when someone submits that form I want to join tose two fields and set the `scheduled_at` field. After this I also want to run my validator against `scheduled_at`

I tried to put this in my model:

```
attr_accessor :schedule_date, :schedule_time
scheduled_at = schedule_date + ' ' + schedule_time

# Validations
validate :validate_scheduled_at

def validate_scheduled_at
   # Custom validation for 
end
```

But this tells me:

> undefined local variable or method `schedule_date'

Comment: Where exactly in your model did u put this code?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: This code `scheduled_at = schedule_date + ' ' + schedule_time`, is not inside the `validate_scheduled_at` method?

Comment: No, I mean imagine I didn't have a validation. I just want to join both fields to scheduled_at datetime before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'before_validation' callback to your advantage here. Change your model as so:

```
class ModelName
  attr_accessor :schedule_date, :schedule_time, :scheduled_at

  before_validation :combine_date_and_time

  validate :validate_scheduled_at

  def validate_scheduled_at
     # Custom validation for 
  end

  private

  def combine_date_and_time
    self.scheduled_at = schedule_date + ' ' + schedule_time
  end
end
```

The callback will combine both the fields as you wish before validation is executed, allowing your validate scheduled_at method to access the 'scheduled_at' attribute with the value you wanted.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I can't access schedule_time and schedule_at in my model. My log says that those are  nil:NilClass.

Comment: I had assumed you were passing those up in the form? Post you view code.